# Prove that $\alpha$ is congruent to $\beta$

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a curve $\alpha$ = ($\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$) $:$$I$ $\rightarrow$ $R^3$, prove that $\beta$ $:$$I$ $\rightarrow$ $R^3$  is congruent
to $\alpha$ if and only if $\beta$ can be written as 
$\beta(t)= \vec p+ \alpha_1(t)e_1+ \alpha_2(t)e_2+\alpha_3(t)e_3$ 
where $e_i*e_j=\delta_{ij}$
I know that usual translation is enough to prove congruence, but here I can't proceed

Comment: The underlying point is, if you have two orthonormal frames at points of $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ (the standard basis at the origin and some frame $(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3})$ at $p$, say), there exists a unique Euclidean isometry carrying one frame to the other. Does that help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "congruent", but the result seems incorrect: it states that $\alpha \equiv \beta \iff \beta = \vec p + \alpha$, where as I would have said $\alpha \equiv \beta \iff \beta = \vec p + R \alpha$ with $R \in O(3)$. Aren't orthogonal transformations congruences?

Comment: @AlexM. That's what I thought at first. Notation is a bit confusing I think. I think now that : $e_i$ should be interpreted as Frenet vectors : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas